# Change element of list if it holds against some condition or add a new one if not, using Data.Lens

Tags: list, haskell, lenses

I have a list of records and need a function which searches the list for a record with a given name and modify the value of this record *OR* if no record matches append a new record to the resulting list. Here is my code so far:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), pure)
import Data.List (any)

data SomeRec = SomeRec { _name :: String, _val :: Int }
$(makeLenses ''SomeRec)

_find :: (a -> Bool) -> Simple Traversal [a] a
_find _ _ [] = pure []
_find pred f (a:as) = if pred a
                        then (: as) <$> f a
                        else (a:) <$> (_find pred f as)

changeOrCreate :: [SomeRec] -> String -> (Int -> Int) -> [SomeRec]
changeOrCreate recs nameToSearch valModifier = 
  if (any (\r -> r^.name == nameToSearch) recs)
    then over (_find (\r -> r^.name == nameToSearch)) (over val valModifier) recs
    else recs ++ [SomeRec nameToSearch (valModifier 0)]
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way of writing this using `Data.Lens` (without the `if`-construct)? Also, do I have to write the `_find` function or is there something equivalent in the library?

*Update*: Here is a Gist of the source to experiment: https://gist.github.com/SKoschnicke/5795863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
changeOrCreate :: String -> (Int -> Int) -> [SomeRec] -> [SomeRec]
changeOrCreate nameToSearch valModifier = 
  pos . val %~ valModifier
  & outside (filtered (not . has pos)) %~ (. newRec)
  where
    pos :: Traversal' [SomeRec] SomeRec
    pos = taking 1 (traversed . filtered (anyOf name (== nameToSearch)))
    newRec = (SomeRec nameToSearch 0 :)
```

Comment: So, a `Prism` lets me change the list? I think I have to test that to understand completly, will do that tomorrow!

Comment: Works nicely! But as far as I understand, with the use of `filtered`, `pos` is no valid `Traversal` anymore, right? Therefor it's not generally composable with other traversals.

Comment: It's indeed not a valid `Traversal` if you use it to change the `name` field and thus make the predicate not hold anymore ("rules" may break, as demonstrated in Matvey's answer), but otherwise, it is composable with other traversals.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but you can write some like

```
changeOrCreate [] n f = [SomeRec n (f 0)]
changeOrCreate (r:rs) n f | r^.name == n = (over val f) r:rs
                          | otherwise    = r: changeOrCreate rs n f
```

Answer (score 2):

So, `_find` is not actually a [`Traversal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#g:1):

```
> [1..10] & over (_find odd) succ . over (_find odd) succ
[2,2,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
> [1..10] & over (_find odd) (succ . succ)
[3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

That's the same sense [`filtered`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#g:1) is not a traversal.

Getting part can be mimicked with `filtered` (it's okay here since [`Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Type.html#t%3aFold) does not have any laws):

```
> [1..10] ^? _find even
Just 2
> [1..10] ^? _find (> 20)
Nothing
> [1..10] ^? folded . filtered even
Just 2
> [1..10] ^? folded . filtered (> 20)
Nothing
```

Now, assuming "more direct way" is some clever `Traversal`: no, that's not possible, `Traversal`s can not modify the structure of the traversed thing.

Comment: I think I have to read some more about lenses to understand this, but thank you for pointing this out! I assume there is nothing like a `Traversal` which *can* change the structure of the traversed thing?

Comment: That's correct, there's no such thing. The problem is you can't have any nice laws for it.